# How compute divergence and gradient of image in OpenCV?

Tags: opencv, gradient

I know that to implement the following
[image]

I would use this code:

```
Mat o_k;
Mat Lapl;
double lambda;
Laplacian(o_k, Lapl, o_k.depth(), 1, 1, 0, BORDER_REFLECT);
Lapl = 1.0 - 2.0*lambda*Lapl;
```

However, I am trying to implement in OpenCV the following equation:

[image]

I know the `div`, or divergence, term would be like this, right?

```
int ksize = parser.get<int>("ksize");
int scale = parser.get<int>("scale");
int delta = parser.get<int>("delta");
Sobel(res, sobelx, CV_64F, 1, 0, ksize, scale, delta, BORDER_DEFAULT);
Sobel(res, sobely, CV_64F, 0, 1, ksize, scale, delta, BORDER_DEFAULT);
div = sobelx + sobely;
```

Where `res` is the result of the term in parenthesis. But how I get the term in parenthesis?

Or am I doing this wrong? Would `div` above actually be equal to the gradient of `res`? If so, then how do I get the divergence?

**EDIT:**

According to this link, the magnitude can also be computed as `mag = abs(x) + abs(y)`: https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/sobel_derivatives/sobel_derivatives.html#sobel-derivatives

And since the `div` of a gradient is the Laplacian, would the below code be equivalent to the 2nd equation?

```
Sobel(res, sobelx, CV_64F, 1, 0, ksize, scale, delta, BORDER_DEFAULT);
Sobel(res, sobely, CV_64F, 0, 1, ksize, scale, delta, BORDER_DEFAULT);

convertScaleAbs( sobelx, abs_grad_x );
convertScaleAbs( sobely, abs_grad_y );

/// Total Gradient (approximate)
Mat mag;
addWeighted( abs_grad_x, 1, abs_grad_y, 1, 0, mag);

Laplacian(o_k, Lapl, o_k.depth(), 1, 1, 0, BORDER_REFLECT);
Mat top;
top = lambda  * Lapl;

Mat result;
divide(top, mag, result);
```

Comment: You may want to have a look at this: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/29558/what-does-it-mean-by-gradient-divergence-curl-of-a-2d-image-gx-y/29559

Comment: you can get the gradient with sobel or scharr methods. check the documentation

Comment: I see according to this link that `mag = sqrt(gradx + grady)` is the magnitude, which is the bottom term of the parenthesis for the 2nd equation. But how do I get the top term in parenthesis?